# At what point should you request status updates from recruiter

Tags: applications

I submitted my resume for a software development position and several days later I received a "screening call" from a recruiter. After a good conversation, I was instructed to send him some code samples and he would distribute them to the relevant teams. He noted that he was very confident he could get me at least one interview.

After a week, I politely inquired about the status of my application. He told me that he was still waiting to hear back from managers, and that he was meeting with them soon and would be sure to discuss my case and get back to me ASAP.

It has been 2 weeks since I last spoke to him (via email.) Would it be abnormal or rude to contact him again at this point? Is it better to exercise patience in this case or should one be more proactive?

I fear that it might be insulting to the recruiter to send an additional email (particularly if he hasn't forgotten about me)

Comment: It would be pretty normal.  I wouldn't see it as a problem if it's been 2 weeks.  Be aware that recruiters will sometimes place ads to fill their applicant roster without specifically having a job for you.  It wouldn't be unheard of for an applicant to be strung along this way.

Comment: Is this a third-party recruiter or someone employed directly by the company?

Comment: @JeffO it's someone employed directly by the company

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's neither insulting nor rude to contact him again at this point and ask for an update.  In terms of getting the "best results" out of this particular recruiter, it's best to be proactive.  If he has forgotten about you, reminding him will remind him... if he hasn't, he won't be offended unless he's completely worthless, and in that case, no loss.

Having said that, I'm not sure I'd be bothered.  There are always recruiters looking for technically skilled personel, so I'd probably just find another one instead.  If I was even inclined to bother with recruiters, which I'm not.

I'm personally inclined to think of recruiters and job interviews more like first dates... if I'm not impressed, that's the end of it, and I'll find someone else instead.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm certainly not impressed. I know they are losing developers left and right (doesn't sound good right ;) ). However, I find myself with neither the strongest resume nor the highest confidence in my programming skills. So, I'm more willing to take what I can get.

Comment: @user2079802 Nothing wrong with being willing to take what you can get... just make sure you shop around first, so you actually know what you can get, instead of settling for something less, just because it happened to be the first thing that came along.  ... and another similarity to dating, right there. ;)